# Showing that a right-continuous process does not satisfy Kolmogorov's Continuity Criterion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

As part of a larger exercise, we've been tasked to show that the following right-continuous stochastic process $X$ does not satisfy the requirements of Kolmogorov's Continuity Criterion.

Let $\Omega = [0, 1]$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}([0, 1])$ and $P = \lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$. Let $Y$ be the identity map on $\Omega$, i.e. $Y(\omega) = \omega$. Define $X = (X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ by $X_t = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{Y \leq t\}}$. Hence, $X_t(\omega) = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{Y(\omega) \leq t \}} = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{[0, t]\}}(\omega)$.

For those interested, the Continuity Criterion is given as:

If there exist constants $\alpha, \beta, K > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left|X_t - X_s\right|^\alpha \leq K \left|t - s\right|^{1 + \beta},
\end{align*}
for all $s, t \in [0, T]$, then there exists a continuous modification $\hat{X}$ of $X$.

The objective is to show that the Continuity Criterion does not hold in its current form stated above, but also to show that it does hold if we take $\beta = 0$.

My problem is that I've no general idea how to solve this exercise. I've tried about a million different pairs of $s, t$ trying to get something that has limit 1 on the left side, and 0 on the right side, but so far I've been unsuccesful.

I think my perception of the problem is wrong as well, since I've no idea why the $\beta$ is even important in this case, why taking $\beta = 0$ would solve the issue.

The main part of this exercise revolves around showing that $X$ has no continuous modification, and I think I've managed this fairly well by first showing it for a dense subset and then extrapolating to the whole of $T$, it's just this part that is bugging me..

Any helpful hints or insights are much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $s\lt\omega\leqslant t$, then $X_s(\omega)=0$ and $X_t(\omega)=1$, hence the inequality 
$$\tag{1}  |X_t(\omega)- X_s(\omega)| \geqslant \mathbf 1_{(s,t]}(\omega)  $$ 
takes place. Integrating with respect to the Lebesgue measure, we deduce that for each $\alpha\gt 0$, 
$$\mathbb E|X_t-X_s|^\alpha\geqslant|t-s|.$$
If $\beta\gt 0$, then the inequality 
$$\tag{$\star$} \mathbb{E}\left|X_t - X_s\right|^\alpha \leq K \left|t - s\right|^{1 + \beta}$$
cannot hold, otherwise we would have for any $s\lt t$, $K|t-s|^\beta\gt 1$.

Actually, inequality (1) is an inequality (it was not used for the previous part), hence $\mathbb E|X_t-X_s|=|t-s|$ and  $(\star)$ holds with $\beta=0$.

Comment: Brilliant as always Davide, thank you very much!